# How to apply a specific function to typer character columns only in a dataset?

Tags: r

My test dataset

```
    df=structure(list(Atencion = c(871739L, 866903L, 847986L, 872950L, 
860503L, 868579L), NomAtenTipoBase = c("Hospitalización", "Hospitalización", 
"Hospitalización", "Urgencias", "Hospitalización", "Hospitalización"
), FecIngreso = structure(c(1656598680, 1656161220, 1654693680, 
1656675480, 1655690640, 1656423480), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Plan_Del_Contrato = c("ATENCIÓN PGP ONCOLÓGICO SUBSIDIADO - CONTRIBUTIV", 
"SANTANDER-C", "PBS-C", "ACCIDENTES DE TRANSITO", "ATENCIÓN INTEGRAL ONCOLOGIA REG- SUBSIDIADO", 
"ARL")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I require to recursively apply this function only to the columns with character type (`NomAtenTipoBase` and `Plan_Del_Contrato`), instead of applying the code on each column:

```
df$NomAtenTipoBase = stri_enc_toutf8(df$NomAtenTipoBase)
df$Plan_Del_Contrato = stri_enc_toutf8(df$Plan_Del_Contrato)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `across` with `where`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
df <- df %>%
     mutate(across(where(is.character), stri_enc_toutf8))
```

---

Or with `base R` , find the character column and update only those by looping over the subset of columns

```
i1 <- sapply(df, is.character)
df[i1] <- lapply(df[i1], stri_enc_toutf8)
```